# Flutter: find out which lint / analyzer rules are enabled at what level

Tags: flutter, dart, sonarqube, lint

One can [analyze lint issues](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) in a Flutter project by running `flutter analyze`. Also, by providing a `analysis_options.yaml` file, one can enable/disable/change severity of rules, as well as import a predefined set of rules from other locations (e.g. pedantic, or from a relative path).

But is there a way to show the complete list of enabled rules, as well as their severity?
I mean the final merged version of all of them. This would be incredibly helpful, especially for exporting the same config to use in [sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/).

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can open the Analyzer Server Diagnostics by pressing the gear icon in the Analysis tab; opening a new browser window.

[image: View analyzer diagnostics]

There, open the `Context` for your package and it shows the list of **all** activated Lint rules as seen by the analysis server

[image: Lint rules]

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot! 

Comment: Also: It's surprising I didn't find this - and still can not - find any documentation on this via Google. Let's see how many upvotes this comment gets from future users who find this StackOverflow post instead of any official docs ;-)